# How is chi-squared association / keyness calculated in quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to understand the chisquare calculation behind the associations (or correlation) of keywords in a target and reference group.

```
library(quanteda)    
pres_corpus <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, President %in% c("Obama", "Trump"))

# Remove Punctuation and Numbers
tokensAll <- tokens(pres_corpus, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers= TRUE)

# Removing stopwords before constructing bigrams
tokensNoStopwords <- tokens_remove(tokensAll, stopwords("english"))

# Bigram
tokensNgramsNoStopwords <- tokens_ngrams(tokensNoStopwords,  n=2, concatenator = "_")
dtm = dfm(tokensNgramsNoStopwords, tolower = TRUE, groups = "President")

# Calculate keyness and determine Trump as target group
(result_keyness <- textstat_keyness(dtm, target = "Obama"))[1]
```

The manual calculation of textstat_keyness() is shown below -

```
# Number of words
sums <- rowSums(dtm)

# frequency of target
a = as.numeric(dtm[1,1])

# frequency of reference
b = as.numeric(dtm[2,1])

# total of all target words minus freq. of target
c = sums[1] - a

# total of all reference words minus freq. of reference
d = sums[2] - b

N = (a+b+c+d)
E = (a+b)*(a+c) / N
(N * abs(a*d - b*c)^2) / ((a+b)*(c+d)*(a+c)*(b+d)) * ifelse(a > E, 1, -1)
```

It matches with the score derived from textstat_keyness( ) function. However, it does not match if I use chisq.test()-

```
(tt = as.table(rbind(c(a, b), c(c, d))))
suppressWarnings(chi <- stats::chisq.test(tt))
(t_exp <- chi$expected[1,1])
(chi2 = unname(chi$statistic) * ifelse(tt > t_exp, 1, -1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in the application of [Yates's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity) for the 2x2 Chi-squared test.  `chisq.test()` applies the correction by default.  In your manual computation, you have not applied the correction.

So:

```
textstat_keyness(dtm, target = "Obama")[1]
##           feature     chi2        p n_target n_reference
## 1 fellow_citizens 0.647129 0.421141        2           0
```

And without the correction:

```
chisq.test(tt, correct = FALSE)

##  Pearson's Chi-squared test
## 
## data:  tt
## X-squared = 0.64713, df = 1, p-value = 0.4211
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. It's really helpful. Could you please give an example (except speeches) where this comparative association analysis can be used? I couldn't understand how association analysis is different from tf-idf. I think we can identify important key words using tf-idf. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it’s often used for sentiment analysis, for instance, to discover the most common positive and negatively associated words. (See https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html#most-positive-negative for examples.) tf-idf has the disadvantage of removing words that occur in every document (or with the collapsed form of pairwise association in `textstat_keyness()`, two documents. So a word that occurred in both, even if its occurrence were uneven, would be zero-weighted by tf-idf - not what you want for this application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation. Special thanks for developing quanteda package.

Comment: Last question - If my objective is to find important features (or words) in a corpus where there are many documents (not just two), do you see any issue of using tf-idf as technique to find important keywords?

Comment: They are not really key words, just those with high term frequency but low document frequency. Sometimes “key” words are found in many documents, but at very different rates. Anyway this would be a good new question, possibly for Cross Validated.